# In SR2, what causes some homies' phones to give a busy signal when called (not able to be a follower)?

Tags: saints-row-2

I've noticed that in SR2, some homies can not be called to be a follower on certain instances (their phones will give out a busy signal). In some cases this could be shortly after they were dismissed, or after the player character or the homie get smoked (died). This is [like in SR3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/133421/4797), and unlike in SR4, where homies can be asked to follow you almost anytime and anywhere, even when you are on certain missions and even shortly after they were just dismissed.

I know that homies can't be called as a follower most of the time when you currently have a mission active. But even if I don't have any mission active, some homies' phones still give out a busy signal when called. I also know that there's a cooldown period before you can call a homie again to be a follower after they have been dismissed.

In instances where I don't have a mission active, **what causes the homies' phones to give a busy signal when called? And how does this work?**

- How long is the cooldown period before you can call a homie again to be a follower after they have been called previously (after being dismissed or after the homie / player character gets smoked)?
- Are there locations where you can't call a homie to be a follower?
- Are there certain events (not necessarily active missions) where homies won't be able to be a follower?

Comment: It has been alot longer time since I played SR2 :p, but I think there is a cooldown timer aswell. You are going the otherway around it seems? From 4 to 3 to 2? :p

Comment: @Lyrion Yeah, I'm looking to know more details about the cooldown timer, like how long it is. Actually, 3 was the first Saints Row game I played, followed by IV, and then currently, 2. =)

Comment: I've been looking around abit, and no one knows for sure for 3: http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Homies if you look at cooldown timers it is apparently hardcoded in the exe. But some say 15 minutes, i'm thinking if you really want to know you should call one, dismiss it and start a timer and keep trying every 5 minutes :p